# How can I replicate all tables in one schema in postgresql11?

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql11 and I'd like to setup logical replication between two db instances. I have read the doc https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createpublication.html.

I see there is an option to set `FOR ALL TABLES` but it includes all tables under all schemas of the database. Is there a way for me to sync all tables under on particular schemas? I don't want to list of tables so looking for a solution to cover all tables automatically

Comment: You can dynamically generate a SQL statement that includes all tables for a specific schema, e.g. in a `do` block or put it into a procedure.

Answer (score 1):

This feature will be available in [postgresql 15](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/35/3139/). (please don't use development version in production) So, there is no such feature in postgresql 11.